# Do I need to stop processes like mysql or apache before "reboot"?

Tags: centos, mysql, reboot, runlevel

I have been wondering if issuing a reboot command safely stops running LAMP processes like MySQL or Apache?

Comment: What system are you on?

Comment: CentOS 6.2 (the latest).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it's installed as a service (most likely case), it should get the command to stop on the way down automatically.

If it's not, then you should stop them first.

Edit: Now that I have a few minutes at a computer, I'll expand on this a bit.

One way to view your available services is to use the `service` command (typically `/sbin/service`)

As `root` (or using `sudo` or a similar command) you can use the following:

```
# service --status-all
# service --status-all | grep httpd
# service --status-all | less
# service httpd status
```

You can also use the `chkconfig` command (again as `root`)

```
# chkconfig --list
# chkconfig | grep httpd
# chkconfig --list | less
```

If the applications were installed during OS installation or via `yum` this will most likely by the case for you and they will stop when the OS is shutting down or rebooting.

If they were installed via some non-standard way and not as a service, then it would be best to stop them first, otherwise the OS will forcefully stop them before shutting down (`killall`)

Answer (score 1):

They don't need to be stopped per se, but they need to know that they have to flush all current writes to disk and switch to read-only. It just so happens that stopping them prevents them from writing any more to the disk by default (since they no longer *exist*). Most shutdown processes stop any running daemons.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes (not on Linux, though) there's a difference between a reboot initiated by `reboot` command and orderly shutdown & reboot (`shutdown -r`); the latter runs any shutdown scripts, the former doesn't and kernel simply terminates all running processes (forcibly with SIGKILL, if need be)

Comment: I know this is the case in older (over 10 years ago) Unix systems (hp-ux, Solaris, aix). I haven't work with the newer versions of them, is it still true?

Comment: I administer a mix of Linux, AIX, HPUX & BSD systems. As a matter of habit I always use shutdown -h and then manually restart.  I only use reboot and poweroff if I know that no critical services are running, e.g. non-production systems, i.e. mostly when hacking on my own servers.

Comment: @CyberFonic so which reboot params should I use before restarting working server with apache, mysql and php? Is there is a reboot command with params that will wait until processes will finish their task and then reboot?

Comment: @Eryk Wróbel, I can't answer your question directly because I don't use any of the subsystems you mention. If I was administering such a system, then I would simply write a script to directly stop those services and only then call reboot. Mind you, most of my servers go for months without a reboot.